# mvc 1.0 doesnt work on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have a strange problem with my MVC 1.0 application that I published on IIS6. When I try to surf to the pages no routes match and I get page not found.

I have installed 3.5sp1 on the webserver and everything needed.

Seems like there is lots of files missing (?) or the filestructure isnt the same as in my project folder.

What might be wrong here?

/M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you set up wildcard mappings?

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thanks, everybody always forgets the wild card mappings.