# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application onto IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

This is driving me crazy. I written a simple ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application I published this onto my local machine and onto the production server. Both the local and production connects to the same 3rd database server.

The application works fine on the local machine but not on the production server. On the production server I get an error message like: “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server...”

The production server is running IIS6 and I already enabled wild card. I also tried to delete all references to aspmembership by removing the accountcontroller.
The funny thing is even when I try to make a default ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application and publish it onto the production I get the same error message and there are no database connections anywhere.

How do I solve this or where do I start? Is this a MS SQL problem or a ASP.NET MVC 1.0 on IIS 6 problem?

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Sounds like the wrong connection type is used. Can you try specifying TCP/IP (or whichever actually works) explicitly? Perhaps named pipes or something similar is being used on the server? Also, paste the entire error message, including the stack trace and any messages.

Either way, this sounds completely unrelated to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @bzlm, it's happening even if there are no databases involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when trying to make MVC 1 and WebForms co-exist.  In the end I had to include this into the web.config file.

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing"/>
```

[asp.net-mvc and webforms co-existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904524/asp-net-mvc-and-webforms-co-existing)